# How can I make a grid inside a flex container responsive in CSS without disrupting the layout of the outer flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox, containers, overflow, css-grid

I am trying to use a grid display a list of items inside flex display. I was able to display correctly but the grid is overflowing outside the container.

My expected result was the container grows as the data on that is displayed on the grid without overflowing.

As the list goes on increasing, the list is overflowing the height of the container rather than container height increasing.

- How can I expand the flex container without causing overflow?

Note: I've tried solutions like adding a vertical scrollbar, which works, but it's not meeting my requirements.
Update: Added a recreatable html and css

```css
.dis{
    display: flex;
    height:auto;
}

.dlist {
    display: grid;
    row-gap: 5%;
    column-gap: 10%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.dgrid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 10px;
    gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="dis">
         <div class="dlist">
            <article class="dgrid">
               <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
            </article>
            <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
             <article class="dgrid">
                <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
             </article>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Added a screenshot where the grid is overlapping the container. The problem is the container is not growing and **I am unable to figure of why the grid is overflowing and not the outer container.**
[image]

Comment: Does the demo above show the problem? Some subtle background color on key elements can really help visualize.

Comment: Dude, provide an example code that reproduces the problem!

Comment: @imhvost - Added the reproducible code. Thanks.

Comment: It is still not clear what the problem is

Comment: @imhvost added the screenshot as well for better understanding where the grid is overflowing and the container is of the same size (Not growing with the grid. I want to know why and what would be the work around ).

Comment: Now I understood what it was about and gave an answer

Comment: @imhvost Thank you. I was able to solve my issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that you are using a `gap` percentage value. You will have to use other units:

```css
.dis {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}

.dlist {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  /* gap: 5% 10%; */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.dgrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  gap: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="dis">
  <div class="dlist">
    <article class="dgrid">
      <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
    </article>
    <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
     <article class="dgrid">
       <h3>John elizabeth</h3>
     </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh no..! Thank you so much! I wasted 4 days on this ! and Now, I understood why the container is not expanding. I removed the gap for the display grid and added padding to the inner items inside the grid. It's working now.